# Displaying Data

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a drop down list which is populated from a MYSQLi query. I want the user to select an option and the values/record associated pulled from the database and displayed to the user based upon FirstName.

my table does not have an id column (I didnt make any. Starts with FirstName)

It displays the table with column titles but it does not fetch the data dynamically from the db which happens to be coded in the while loop in [view code] below. **I've spent my whole day and whole night trying to figure this out. Help :(**

**list code**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form_update" method="post" action="update_test.php">
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ismat_db");
  //============== check connection
 if(mysqli_errno($con))
  {
echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
   }
else
{
echo "Connected to mySQL</br>";
 }

//This creates the drop down box
echo "<select name= 'FirstName'>";
echo '<option value="">'.'--- Please Select Person ---'.'</option>';
//$query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,FirstName FROM persons");
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT FirstName FROM persons");
//$query_display = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM persons");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
echo "<option value='". $row['id']."'>".$row['FirstName']
 .'</option>';
 }
echo '</select>';
 ?> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
 </form>
 <br/><br/>
  <a href="main.html"> Go back to Main Page </a>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**View Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Update Data</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 
 $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ismat_db");
 if(mysqli_errno($con))
 {
echo "Can't Connect to mySQL:".mysqli_connect_error();
  }

 if(isset($_POST['FirstName']))
  {
 $name = $_POST['FirstName'];

  $fetch="SELECT Firstname FROM persons WHERE Firstname = '".$name."'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con,$fetch);
  if(!$result)
   {
   echo "Error:".(mysqli_error($con));
    }
   //display the table
  echo '<table border="1">'.'<tr>'.'<td align="center">'. 'From Database'. '</td>'.'</tr>';
  echo '<tr>'.'<td>'.'<table border="1">'.'<tr>'.'<td>'.'First Name'.'</td>'.'<td>'.'
   LastName'.'</td>'.'<td>'. 'Gender' .'</td>'.'<td>'. 'Subject'. '</td>'.'<td>'.'
   Hobbies'  .'</td>'.'</tr>';

 //Supposed to collect data from db-I tried using _array,_assoc instead of _row 
 //and got   mysqli_result()
  //   requires one parameter given boolean

 while($data=mysqli_fetch_row($result))  
     {
         echo ("<tr><td>$data[0]</td><td>$data[1]</td><td>$data[2]</td><td>$data[3]</td> <td>$data[4] </td></tr>");
}
    echo '</table>'.'</td>'.'</tr>'.'</table>';
  }
 ?>
```

Comment: I'm sure it's obvious to you, but, er - what is your question?

Comment: @enhzflep The associated row upon selection of option from the drop down box is not showing up from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are examining the 'FirstName' post-data, which is the value of the SELECT. However, this value will be the value from one of the OPTIONs, which is set to ID. You should put the FirstName's as the values of the OPTIONs.

Also, you are not currently retrieving the IDs from the database.

Comment: thanks for replying, do you mean to say that I have to change echo "<select = 'FirstName'>";

Comment: No. This: `echo "<option value='". $row['FirstName']."'>".$row['FirstName']`

Comment: Did that, It's giving this for an error 

Notice: Undefined offset: 1
Notice: Undefined offset: 2
Notice: Undefined offset: 3
Notice: Undefined offset: 4
Mark _This is FirstName displayed that I had selected from the drop down.

and it is pointing towards the while in the code section -> view code

Comment: Your query in **View Code** only selects FirstName, but the table tries to print Last Name, Gender, Subject, and Hobbies.

Comment: @Barmar - but isn't $data[0] to $data[4] fetching all 5 columns from the table? or do you mean that I have to write more SELECT queries and execute them?

Comment: No, the only columns that are fetched from the table are the ones named in the `SELECT` statement. It should be `SELECT LastName, FirstName, Gender, Subject, Hobbies FROM ...`.

Comment: Your query is `SELECT Firstname FROM` so it only fetches 1 column (FirstName). You might use `SELECT Firstname, LastName, etc. FROM`.

Comment: **Thanks ALOT it's done - just changed the query **

$fetch="SELECT Firstname,LastName,Gender,Subject,Hobbies FROM persons WHERE Firstname = '".$name."'";

What a bugger!

Answer (score 0):

I realize I've used PDO instead of mySqli as you have. With that triviality aside, if I've understood your question, this should be more than enough to put you on the right track.

If you run it, you'll note that the only time the customers lastName is displayed is in response to a form submission, in which they were the chosen company.

**testQuery.php**

```
<?php
    // check if the name of the select box is present in the POST variables. if so, the form is being submitted.
    // If not, it's a fresh load of the page (the page has been requested by something other than itself)
    if (isset($_POST["selectedCustomer"]))
        $formSubmitted = true;
    else
        $formSubmitted = false;


    // connect to the mysql server
    $pdo = null;
    try
    {
        $userName = 'root';     // enter the appropriate values HERE
        $password = '';             // and HERE

        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost', $userName, $password);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        die('Can\'t establish a connection to the database: ');
    }

    // create a database to answer thisa forum question
    $pdo->query("create database forumQuestion");
    $pdo->query("use forumQuestion");

    // create a table
    $queryStr = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `firstName` varchar(128) NOT NULL, `lastName` varchar(128) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ";
    $pdo->query($queryStr);

    // insert some data
    $queryStr = "INSERT INTO `customer` (`id`, `firstName`, `lastName`) VALUES (1, 'ILM 3d studios', 'Industrial Light & Magic'), (2, 'Airwalk clothing', 'Why walk on the ground?');";
    $pdo->query($queryStr);
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php if ($formSubmitted == true)
        {
            $submittedCustomerId = $_POST["selectedCustomer"];

            $queryStr = "select * from customer where id = :id";
            $params = array(":id" => $submittedCustomerId);
            $query = $pdo->prepare($queryStr);
            $query->execute($params);

            $onlyResult = $query->fetch();
            printf("Form has been submitted.<br>");
            printf("id(%d), firstName(%s), lastName(%s)", $submittedCustomerId, $onlyResult["firstName"], $onlyResult["lastName"]);
        }
          else
            printf("Form awaiting submission");
    ?>
    <hr>
    <h2>Select a ccustomer</h2>
    <form action="testQuery.php" method="POST">
        <select name='selectedCustomer'>
            <option value='0'>-- Select a customer --</option>
            <?php
                $queryStr = "select * from customer";
                $query = $pdo->prepare($queryStr);
                $query->execute();
                while ($curCustomer = $query->fetch())
                {
                    printf("<option value='%d'>%s</option>", $curCustomer["id"], $curCustomer["firstName"]);
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type='submit' value='submit form'/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice, the problem was in my query - after changing it to 

$fetch="SELECT Firstname,LastName,Gender,Subject,Hobbies FROM persons WHERE Firstname = '".$name."'";

it got fixed, btw in your code - where is $formSubmitted defined - if you dont mind me asking

Comment: Great, glad you found the problem. Your question made me notice a mistake - the top couple of lines of my snippet didn't display properly. I've fixed them now - the $formSubmitted var is defined and initialized in those first couple of lines. :)

Comment: yeah thanks alot, works perfectly. Really helpful and I see that you wrote some php code before the doctype tag, was there any specific reason? or it doesnt matter much? and that which approach is better - PDO or procedural mysqli??

Comment: @enhzflep- And basically what you did on one page - create db, table etc Ive done all of that on separate pages and so this code is very helpful in learning for me who is a newbie to php

Comment: @AbbasAnsari - glad to hear its helpful for you. I often prefer to put php code **that produces no output** before the html, where both are in the same file. I find it clearer to read. PDO is better than MySqli, since it supports a greater number of database and database providers. Both are better than unmanaged access to the databases (have methods to prevent sql injection attacks. See the $params=array(":id"=>$submittedCustomerId) term for an example. See here for PDO vs MySqli: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/

Comment: wow cool thanks .. great link.. and help I now plan to finish the mysqli tasks that ive done and then transfer them to PDO :D thanks alot.